# Validate specific format without using "-" to split the string

Tags: javascript, validation

Hi i need to validate a string before sending my form, the format must be

LLLL999999XXX

Where L is any letter
9 is any number
X is any letter or number.

I figure out how to do this using - to split, the problem is that my users use to enter this value with out the - , so its going to be strage if i ask for a - in the format. (in this moment i ask , pls enter format LLLL-999999-XXX wich is no good.)

How can i validate this, without using - , any ideas? sorry im newbie at javascript

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function RFC(cual)
{
mensaje = "pls enter this format LLLL-999999-XXX"
pat = /[a-z]|[A-Z]/
pat2 = /[a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]/
val = cual.split("-")
if (val.length == 3){
    if(val[0].length == 4){
        if(!comp(val[0],pat)){
            alert( mensaje)
            return false
            }
        }
    if(val[1].length == 6){
        if(isNaN(val[1])){
            alert('no es un numero')
            return false
            }
        }
    if(val[2].length == 3){
        if(!comp(val[2],pat2)){
            alert(mensaje)
            return false
            }
        }
else{
    alert(mensaje)
    return false
    }
}
else{
    alert(mensaje)
    return false
    }
return true
}
function comp(cual,pa){
for(m=0;m<cual.length;m++){
    if(!pa.test(cual.charAt(m))){
        return false
        break
        }
    }
return true
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use the regex as below:

```
/^[a-z]{4}[0-9]{6}[a-z0-9]{3}$/i
```

If you want `-` as optional:

```
/^[a-z]{4}-?[0-9]{6}-?[a-z0-9]{3}$/i
```

Comment: I'd only add capital letters as well

Comment: @AndreyStukalin If only capital letter is allowed, then change `[a-z]` to `[A-Z]` and remove `i` modifier.

Comment: Thanks i just learn that you can do this. Great! there is always an easy way.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED:

```
var input = "LLLL999999XXX";

var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z]{4}\d{6}[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}$/;

if( input.match(pattern) ){
    alert("true");
}else{
    alert("false");
}
```

See the working code at:

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gS452/2/)